# Get string between quote character

Tags: android, substring

I have a string like

```
"/d/WdTkRcxA/" + (446767 % 51245 + 446767 % 913) + "/Test%20vol.zip"
```

I need the values between the `"` character and the `(` `)` characters.

```
/d/WdTkRcxA/
446767 % 51245 + 446767 % 913
/Test%20vol.zip
```

I know how to get the value between the `(` `)` characters with

```
String result = result.substring(result.indexOf("(")  + 1, result.indexOf(")"));
```

but I am having trouble getting **/d/WdTkRcxA/** and **/Test%20vol.zip**

Can somebody please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case in which substrings get a bit too complicated, so it's better to use regex. Using this pattern: `["(]([^\)"]*)[")]`, you can extract the targeted strings from that text:

```
String text = "\"/d/WdTkRcxA/\" + (446767 % 51245 + 446767 % 913) + \"/Test%20vol.zip\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\"(]([^\\)\"]*)[\")]");

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    String value = m.group(1);

    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Result:

```
/d/WdTkRcxA/
446767 % 51245 + 446767 % 913
/Test%20vol.zip
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, many thx.
I need to assign the values /d/WdTkRcxA/ and /Test%20vol.zip to a seperate string.

val1 = /d/WdTkRcxA/
val2 = /Test%20vol.zip

Can this also be done with your code, it seems to work but the first value (/d/WdTkRcxA/) goes lost.

Comment: @Simon How about defining an `ArrayList` before the `while` loop and adding each `value` to it in place of the `System.out.println` line?

Comment: Yeah that will do it.